# NoMethodError, undefined method in my controller Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm getting NoMethodError at /article

> undefined method 'article_category' for Mongoid::Criteria

**Article model**

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :title, type: String
  field :content, type: String

  belongs_to :user
  #kategorie
  belongs_to :article_category
```

**Article controler**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def article
    @article = Article.order_by(created_at: 'desc').page params[:page]
  end

  def view_article
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**ArticleCategory model**

```
class ArticleCategory
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps


  field :name, type: String

  has_many :articles


end
```

**Article_category controller**

```
class ArticleCategoriesController < ApplicationController

 def category # Give the view all categories to list
  @categories = ArticleCategory.order("created_at DESC")
 end

 def show
   @category = ArticleCategory.find(params[:id])
 end

end
```

**routes**

```
  get 'article', to: 'articles#article'
  get 'article/:id', to: 'articles#view_article', as: 'view_article'
  resources :article_categories do
  resources :articles, shallow: true
end
```

Is there everything good with my category controller ?

In my article view  i'm displaying it in this way.

```
<%= link_to @article.article_category.name, @article.article_category -%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in `ArticlesController#article`:

```
def article
  @article = Article.order_by(created_at: 'desc').page params[:page]
end
```

That sequence of `order_by` and `page` calls is just building a query so you have a `Mongoid::Criteria` in `@article` rather than the single `Article` instance that your template apparently expects.

I'm not sure but the presence of `view_article` and its `article/:id` route suggests that your `article` method should look like:

```
def article
  @articles = Article.order_by(created_at: 'desc').page params[:page]
  # ------^
end
```

and the corresponding view should iterate over `@articles` to display each article.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is complaining that it does not know how to hook up the relationship between Article and ArticleCategory. It may not be able to infer the name of the class in Article?

Try adding the class_name to the definition of the relationship.

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :title, type: String
  field :content, type: String

  belongs_to :user
  #kategorie
  belongs_to :article_category, class_name: "ArticleCategory"
```